# Getting data from Magento database into order/invoice emails and PDF

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, email-templates

I have googled for hours on end for a solution to this, but I cannot find an answer.
Really hope StackExchange can help me out.

My goal is to get the customer comment, if any, added into my order/invoice emails defined in `System > Transactional Emails` and also in the `PDF` that the back-end generates when "Print" is pressed.

I have `Magento 1.7.0.2` running with `GoMage Light Checkout 5.7`.

I'm thinking the easiest way to get the data accessible in both the email and PDF could be to use `System > Custom Variables`.

The field I want in the email is from the table `sales_flat_order`, the column is named `gomage_checkout_customer_comment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the fields to your email, go to system transactional email then edit/import those template.

Then add the following code where you want it to show.

```
{{var order.gomage_checkout_customer_comment}}
```

To add these field to your pdf see [Add custom attribute to Magento’s PDF invoice](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/)

Comment: I have added {{var order.gomage_checkout_customer_comment}} to my mail template and that works great. Thank you. :) And I have followed the guide to the PDF changes, but nothing changes on the PDFs. Shouldn't the Inchoo code be activated somehow in Magento? Or does that happen autimatically?

Comment: Yes you need to activate it .... see Activating Our Module @ http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/